# Perfect forwarding in a template class

Tags: c++, templates, perfect-forwarding

I have a template class and within that class I have a static template function with universal/forwarding reference parameters. The idea is to perfect forward arguments to the function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

//Type traits
template <typename T>
struct is_lreference_const
{
    static const bool value = std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value && std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value;
};

template <typename T>
struct is_lvreference
{
    static const bool value = std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value && !std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value;
};

struct Bar{};

template <class... Args>
struct FooClass;

//Perfect forward to FooClass::impl()
template <class... T>
inline void foo(T&&... args) {
  FooClass<T&&...>::impl(std::forward<T>(args)...);
}

template <typename T>
struct FooClass<T> {
    inline static void impl(T&& b) {
      if constexpr (is_lvreference<T>::value)
          std::cout << "T&" << std::endl;
      else if constexpr (is_lreference_const<T>::value)
          std::cout << "const T&" << std::endl;
      else if constexpr (std::is_rvalue_reference<T>::value)
          std::cout << "T&&" << std::endl;
      else 
          std::cout << "T" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  const Bar b2;
  foo(b2);  
  foo(Bar{});
  Bar b;
  foo(b);
}
```

This all works fine and the output is as expected:

```
const T&
T&&
T&
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5Pz9P9)

However, if I was to change the `foo()` function like this:

```
template <class... T>
inline void foo(T&&... args) {
  FooClass<T...>::impl(std::forward<T>(args)...);
}
```

Notice that the `FooClass` class doesn't get a forwarding reference. Then the output is:

```
const T&
T
T&
```

The value category for the rvalue reference is not passed to the function `impl()` even though I'm using `std::forward`. Why does this happen? Is it because I'm not calling `impl()` in a deducible context as T has already been deduced for `FooClass`? How to avoid such an issue?

(This question is related to another [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65502524/how-to-avoid-code-duplicates-with-class-template-specializations/65502817#comment115808351_65502817) posted earlier today).

### Edit

I changed `FooClass<T>::impl()` to be a template function. Then I found that `else if constexpr (std::is_rvalue_reference<T>::value)` was never true. I [discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373881/why-forwarding-reference-does-not-deduce-to-rvalue-reference-in-case-of-rvalue) ths was because rvalues are deduced to be of type `T` and not `T&&`. So I added some print functions and found that perfect forwarding now worked:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

//Type traits
template <typename T>
struct is_lreference_const
{
    static const bool value = std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value && std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value;
};

template <typename T>
struct is_lvreference
{
    static const bool value = std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value && !std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value;
};

struct Bar{};

template <class... Args>
struct FooClass;

//Perfect forward to FooClass::impl()
template <class... T>
inline void foo(T&&... args) {
  FooClass<T&&...>::impl(std::forward<T>(args)...);
}

template<typename T>
void printme(const T&) {
    std::cout << "constant lvalue reference" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void printme(T&) {
    std::cout << "lvalue reference" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void printme(T&&) {
    std::cout << "rvalue reference" << std::endl;
}


template <typename T>
struct FooClass<T> {
    template <typename Arg>
    inline static void impl(Arg&& b) {
      printme(std::forward<Arg>(b));
  }
};

int main()
{
  const Bar b2;
  foo(b2);  
  foo(Bar{});
  Bar b;
  foo(b);
}
```

Output:

```
constant lvalue reference
rvalue reference
lvalue reference
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9dqrq9)

Comment: `T&&` in `impl(T&& b)` is not a forwarding reference, it is an rvalue one. The only way to get a forwarding reference is to make `impl` a template itself.

Comment: @Evg But `impl()` is a template function.

Comment: `impl()` is not a template in your example, it is a non-template member function of a class template.

Comment: Only function template support perfect forwarding.  If the function doesn't have `template<...>` before it, then the template parameter you are using is already known from instantiating the class so no perfect forwarding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
struct FooClass<T> {
  inline static void impl(T&& b) {
```

`FooClass<X>::impl` takes an `X&&`, and in it `T` is `X`.

If `X` is `int&&`, then `T&&` is `int&& &&` which is `int&&` and `T` is `int&&`.

If `X` is `int`, then `T&&` is `int&&` which is `int&&`, and `T` is `int`.

Within `impl`, you query `T`, not `b`.  So you get a different value if you pass `FooClass` an `int` or and `int&&`, even though the signature of `FooClass<X>::impl` is the same.

The `forward` outside of the call to `impl` has **zero impact** on the code within `impl`; either the call succeeds, or it does not and you get a compilation error.

You are **not** deducing the arguments to `impl`, you are explicitly setting the types.

`forward` is nothing but a conditional `move`.  It isn't magic.

Probably you need to brush up on how std forward, template function argument deduction (especially when you deduce `T&&` parameters), and how reference collapsing works.  If you don't understand that, you might treat std forward as some kind of magic, when it isn't.

Comment: Makes sense. It's not perfect forwarding at all. It's just calling the function within the template class.